# Which number is next?

Tags: matches

[image: Question]
Which number will be in the next Box?

*Just do not triffle that the numbers are in lighting match format.

Comment: Awesome puzzle! We got some pretty smart new puzzlers here.

Comment: source: oyun.tzv.org.tr next time please give the source of the question instead of changing its color.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The next number is

> 44

Reasoning

> The second digit is increasing.
>  The first digit tells you how many matches are used to construct the second digit.